# I'm getting this error when using overlay-navbar in react vite

Tags: reactjs

Uncaught Error: Dynamic require of "C:/Users/AJAY MAURYA/OneDrive/Desktop/React/E-commerce -1/frontend/node_modules/overlay-navbar/dist/lib/ReactNavbar.min.css" is not supported
__require chunk-Q7D65HC4.js:12
js ReactNavbar.js:14
__require2 chunk-Q7D65HC4.js:18
js index.js:13
__require2 chunk-Q7D65HC4.js:18
 overlay-navbar:1

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.